# how to generate a sequences of positive and negative fractional numbers in R

Tags: r

I would like to generate sequences of positives and negatives numbers in a specific interval. For example, I would like to generate `10` numbers in `[0.2,-0.9]` without **zeros**. Here are my tries:

```
x <- sample(0.5:-0.9, 20, replace=T)
x
 [1]  0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5
[16] -0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5
x <- sample(0.2:-0.9, 20, replace=T)
x
 [1]  0.2 -0.8  0.2 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8  0.2 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8  0.2 -0.8
[16] -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8
 x <- seq(0.2, -0.9)
 x
[1]  0.2 -0.8
```

All my tries did not give me what I want. The expected output is, for example,

`0.2, -0.25, 0.3, 0.4, -0.5, 0.5, -0.9, -0.6, 0.7, 0.6`

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below adds the new requirement at the end (about not having 0).

You need `seq` and to have the numbers in the correct order:

```
sample(seq(0.2,from=-0.9,by=.1), 10, replace=T)
```

> ```
> [1] -0.1 -0.6  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.2 -0.8 -0.7 -0.2
> ```

and I recommend `sample_n`:

```
library(dplyr)
sample_n(as_tibble(seq(0.2,from=-0.9,by=.1)), 10, replace=T)
```

> ```
>     value
>     <dbl>
>  1  0.100
>  2 -0.200
>  3  0.   
>  4 -0.100
>  5  0.   
>  6 -0.100
>  7 -0.600
>  8 -0.800
>  9 -0.900
> 10 -0.900
> ```

Update:

You mentioned you don't want 0. There are many ways to accomplish this. The best way probably depends on the set of statistical implications that you prefer if that's important to you. Here are some examples:

Example 1

```
x <- sample(seq(0.2,from=-0.9,by=.1), 10, replace=T)

ifelse(x==0, sample(seq(-.1,from=-0.9,by=.1), 1, replace=T), x)
```

Example 2

```
c(sample(seq(-.1,from=-0.9,by=.1), 5, replace=T),
  sample(seq(.1, 0.2,by=.1), 5, replace=T))
```

You could also use a `while`. Basically for each element you'd take random samples until there's one that's not `== 0`. That's probably how I would do it to avoid polluting the distributional assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have got an error :`Error in sample_n(as_tibble(seq(0.2, from = -0.9, by = 0.1)), 10, replace = T) : 
  could not find function "sample_n"`

Comment: @Maryam You need the library `dplyr`

Comment: @Maryam Happy to help :) Please check the green checkmark if you'd like to mark this as the solution

Comment: I should not have zero. Sorry, I will mention that in the question.

Comment: Of course, I will accept it, I just would just to remove zeros from the output.

Comment: @Maryam OK I can give you an update with no zeros, just a minute